# Can I designate a wifi network as "metered network"

Tags: macos, wifi

On MacOS, is is possible to tell the OS that this is MiFi or shared internet from cell phone and the OS should "save" data as much as possible.

(like Android OS is capable of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike on an iPhone or iPad, MacOS does not have an easy option for selecting [Low Data Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210596). However, there are 3rd party utilities that may be helpful.

See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/network-usage-whitelist-for-cell-tethering-on-osx) older post for a bit more info - [TripMode](https://www.tripmode.ch/) remains an option for setting Low Data Mode on MacOS.

Comment: [Since](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449668/what-is-low-data-mode-on-macos-ventura-wlan-exactly/460953#460953) macOS Ventura 13, [launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MacOS_Ventura&oldid=1159506143#:~:text=launched%20on%20October%2024%2C%202022) October 24, 2022 it is available under *Apple menu > System Settings > Wi-Fi* in the sidebar or *Menu Bar > Wi-Fi status icon > Wi-Fi Settings... .* Then for the active connection at the top *Details... > Low data mode*